# Joining Columns in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have a table which looks like

```
TRANSACTION_ID  VALUE   TRANSACTION_TYPE    AGR_NBR PART_NBR    
1               3456      BOOKING            ABC1    1    
2               345678    BOOKING            ABC2   NULL    
3               45678     BOOKING            ABC1   2    
4               45678     BIING              ABC2   NULL    
5               45678     BILLING            ABC1   1    
6               4775678   BILLING            ABC2   NULL
```

I'm running a simple select on this table as below:

```
SELECT AGR_NBR,PART_NBR,

CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BOOKING' 
    THEN SUM(VALUE)
    END AS BOOKING_VAL,

CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLING' 
    THEN SUM(VALUE)
    END AS BILLINNG_VAL

FROM AA_TEST_TABLE
WHERE AGR_NBR = 'ABC1'

GROUP BY AGR_NBR,PART_NBR,TRANSACTION_TYPE;
```

The output which comes from the above query is:

```
AGR_NBR PART_NBR    BOOKING_VAL BILLINNG_VAL    
ABC1    1           NULL        45678    
ABC1    1           3456        NULL    
ABC1    2           45678       NULL
```

But what i want is for same AGR_NBR & PART like (ABC1 & 1) in this case there should be only 1 row as below & i would prefer to do it a singe select statement if possible as with original data there are lots of formulas & joins & also this is just dummy data for 1 row, but in actual there will N number of rows.

```
AGR_NBR PART_NBR    BOOKING_VAL BILLINNG_VAL    
ABC1    1           3456        45678
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.AGR_NBR, A.PART_NBR, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BOOKING' THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS BOOKING_VAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLING' THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS BILLINNG_VAL
FROM AA_TEST_TABLE A
WHERE A.AGR_NBR = 'ABC1'
GROUP BY A.AGR_NBR, A.PART_NBR;
```

Comment: Got it used this,
 SELECT AGR_NBR,PART_NBR,
SUM(CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BOOKING' 
 THEN VALUE
 END ) AS BOOKING_VAL,
SUM(CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLING' 
 THEN VALUE
 END )AS BILLINNG_VAL
FROM AA_TEST_TABLE
WHERE AGR_NBR = 'ABC1'
GROUP BY AGR_NBR,PART_NBR;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     SELECT AGR_NBR, PART_NBR, SUM(BOOKING_VAL) AS BOOKING_VAL, SUM(BILLING_VAL) AS BILLING_VAL FROM 
       ( 
          SELECT AGR_NBR, PART_NBR, CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BOOKING' THEN SUM( VALUE ) END AS BOOKING_VAL, CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLING' THEN SUM( VALUE ) END AS BILLING_VAL FROM test WHERE AGR_NBR = 'ABC1' GROUP BY AGR_NBR, PART_NBR, TRANSACTION_TYPE 
       )  
     AS t GROUP BY AGR_NBR, PART_NBR
```